# Wget over https segfaults after system recovery

Tags: linux, data-recovery, raspberry-pi, wget, raspbian

Running Raspbian, I had a microSD go bad. I used `ddrescue` to image it and put the image on a good microSD. The system boots, I can ssh in, plex seems to work, samba seems to work, most things seem to work.

However, trying to `wget` anything over HTTPS segfaults. Plain HTTP seems fine. This means I can't update certain packages / package sources, and is generally not great.

I've already reinstalled (`apt install --reinstall`) `wget` and all its dependencies (obtained via `apt-cache depends wget`).

What do I try next?

---

For reference, `wget -d` doesn't give much useful information:

```
$ wget -d https://google.com
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.20.1 on linux-gnueabihf.

Reading HSTS entries from /home/felix/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
Converted file name 'index.html' (UTF-8) -> 'index.html' (UTF-8)
--2021-12-20 21:43:42--  https://google.com/
Certificates loaded: 126
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 142.250.200.46, 2a00:1450:4009:81e::200e
Caching google.com => 142.250.200.46 2a00:1450:4009:81e::200e
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|142.250.200.46|:443... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x01c1cb70 (new refcount 1).
Segmentation fault
```

And the list of dependencies is:

```
$ apt-cache depends wget
wget
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libgnutls30
  Depends: libidn2-0
  Depends: libnettle6
  Depends: libpcre2-8-0
  Depends: libpsl5
  Depends: libuuid1
  Depends: zlib1g
  Conflicts: <wget-ssl>
  Recommends: ca-certificates
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it, here's how for posterity.

**TL;DR**: Use `dpkg --verify` to verify all installed packages, reinstall the borked ones. In one command:

```
$ sudo dpkg --verify | grep -v ' c ' | awk '{print $NF}' | xargs dpkg -S | awk '{print substr($1, 1, length($1)-1)}' | sort | uniq | xargs sudo apt install --reinstall
```

---

Breaking the above command down:

##### `sudo dpkg --verify`

Will list all **installed files** that have been modified since installation. However, this will also list e.g. modified config files, marked with a `c`, which is why we need...

##### `grep -v ' c '`

...this removes all lines matching this pattern, so we can ignore packages for which we've simply changed config files.

##### `awk '{print $NF}'`

This prints only the last column of each line. In the output from the first command, this is the path to the file that failed verification (in my case they all failed md5).

##### `xargs dpkg -S`

Calls `dpkg -S` for each path, which prints out the **package** that owns / installed that path.

##### `awk '{print substr($1, 1, length($1)-1)}'`

Extracts just the package name from the output of `dpkg -S`

##### `sort | uniq`

Sorts package names and then removes duplicates. `sort` is required for `uniq` to work. The reason why we have duplicates is because multiple files in the same package could be borked.

##### `xargs sudo apt install --reinstall`

Reinstalls all the borked packages. In my case, these were:

```
binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf
console-setup-linux
g++-8
gcc-8
grep
iso-codes
libcephfs2:armhf
libglib2.0-0:armhf
libgmp10:armhf
libperl5.28:armhf
libpython2.7-stdlib:armhf
librados2:armhf
libstdc++-8-dev:armhf
man-db
perl-base
poppler-data
```

Kinda glad I found this (`dpkg --verify` mostly) as otherwise I would have forever been worried about random stuff breaking or not working because of this.